# Pandas bidirectional asof merge, vs rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to groupby identifiers over a rolling window.

My data looks like this:

```
>>> df
           identifier  uniqueid
2021-08-01          A       0.0
2021-08-02          B       1.0
2021-08-03          C       2.0
2021-08-04          D       3.0
2021-08-05        NaN       NaN
...               ...       ...
2022-05-23          Z     295.0
2022-05-24         AA     296.0
2022-05-25         AB     297.0
2022-05-26         AC     298.0
2022-05-27        NaN       NaN

[300 rows x 2 columns]
```

Reproducible with:

```
import datetime
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

idx = pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime(2021,8,1), periods=300, freq="D")
names =  ([x for x in string.ascii_uppercase] + ["AA", "AB", "AC", "AD"])*10
uniqueid = range(300)

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
  "identifier" : names,
  "uniqueid":  uniqueid,
}, 
index=idx
)

censor = np.random.random(300) < 0.2
df.iloc[censor, :] = np.nan
```

For each day, for each identifier, I'd like to look back N days and get the most recent uniqueid for that identifier.

So, we'd be walking along days, looking back a window only N large, and then matching each identifier to its most recent uniqueid.  If the most recent one is beyond the window, too bad.

I don't quite know whether I'm looking for an asof join or a rolling window.

My desired output looks like, say `N = 30`

```
2021-08-01           []
2021-08-02           []
...
2021-08-31           [(A, 30), (B, 1),  (C, 2), (D, 3), (G,6).... # notice, E, and F are NA
2021-09-01           [(A, 30), (B, 31), (C, 2), ....
2021-09-02           [(A, 30), (B, 31), (D, 3), ....  # notice, C is NA in 9/2, and 8/3 is now > 30 days away
```

I thought something like this might do it:

```
df.groupby("identifier").rolling(30).agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
```

but:

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 244, index implies 300.
```

Comment: One issue is that the window size is 30, while the groupby operation yields groups of size 10, so there will be no results (or rather, NaNs) anyway. It is another issue, and doesn't explain the error.

Comment: Interesting, why are the groups 10?

Comment: Because you have groups of 10 identical identifiers. That is simply your `*10` in your example.

Comment: It's 30 identifiers, ["A", "B", ... "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD"] then repeated 10 times, so the total series is 300 long.

Comment: 10 *identical* identifiers. So the group-by action results in groups of size 10, to which the window is applied. Easiest to see when skipping the addition of NaNs and using a simple sum and/or max for the aggregate, with windows of 5 and 10 for comparison.

Comment: I think I have not explained my question well enough yet then, because I am trying to ask how to only have a group that does /not/ contain all 10 instances of the same 30 identifiers at once---I'm looking to cross sectionally, within a time slice, have at most 1 of each of the 30 identifiers.

Comment: Oh, right. Then the group by operation doesn't make sense. I got stuck looking at that last line of code, thinking you just wanted to understand the following error. But you more or less want the opposite of group by; let's call it "group unique".

Comment: How do you mean "within a time slice"? Since each date is in the dataframe is different. What is a time slice here? There is no single date with multiple identifiers or uniqueid.

Comment: Is `uniqueid` continually increasing with date (ignoring NaNs)? Or could there be duplicate uniqueids, or a lower value at a later date?

Comment: By time slice, I'm looking for the last 30 days, for any given day.  Let me change the question to be something like 60 days, so it doesn't look so related to the 30 identifiers. That is, "I want the most recent uniqueid for each of the 30 identifiers within the last 60 days, so if it is NA this month, roll back to last month, but no more than that."